# Python and JavaScript: different default parameter behaviour

Tags: javascript, python, language-design

I am trying to solve a puzzle in python and javascript and came across a problem.

Below python and javascript are giving different outputs but they are both interpreter languages. Any idea why they are working like this?

Python snippet

```
def func(a = list()):
    a.append(len(a))
    return a

print(func())
print(func())
```

output:

```
[0]
[0,1]
```

Javascript snippet

```
function func(a = []) {
    a.push(a.length); 
    return a
}

console.log(func())
console.log(func())
```

output:

```
[0]
[0]
```

Comment: Do the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument) help at all?

Comment: They're different languages with different rules, the fact that their default implementation uses interpretation is irrelevant.

Comment: I would change the title to "Python and JavaScript: different default parameter behavior"

Answer (score 2):

By specifying a default parameter, it will store it once, you thus modify and return the *same* list. This is one of the major reasons *not* to work with *mutable* values as default parameters.

Usually what one does is work with `None`, or some other variable, and turn this into a list, so:

```
def func(a=None):
    if a is None:
        a = []  # creating a new list
    a.append(len(a))
    return a
```

The default value is thus *not* stored as an expression. The expresion is evaluated when the function is compiled (for the first time) and then the *result* of that expression is *reused* each function call.

As for JavaScript, it will each time evaluate the expression again, and thus construct a new list.